# Replacing EventBus with RxJava - N subscribers always listening

Tags: android, rx-java

I am replacing an `EventBus` pattern with `RxJava` in an Android app. I had events to alert any interested parties of updates to data in my cache singleton. Any time a web service was called, the data would be updated, and the subscribers would be alerted via a posted event.

I have something close to this set up in RxJava with `AsyncSubject`. The observers get a single event from the subject, but then they get an `onComplete` event and unsubscribe. This works as the UI first loads, but when the data needs to be refreshed, there are no subscribers to be notified. How do I tell those `Subscribers` to keep listening for more `onNext` events from the `Subject`?

I need a `Subject` that will report the most recent item. `PublishSubject` only emits items after subscription, so it doesn't quite meet my needs. My subscribers start observing at different times (possibly after the first data event), so I need the Subject to emit the last item observed and then keep the stream open for subsequent items. It seems like a combination of AsyncSubject and PublishSubject is what I need. Is there some way to accomplish this with the built in classes, or do I need to create my own subject?

```
WebServiceObservable OR CacheObservable
                  ^
                  |
             AsyncSubject
                  ^
                  |
                /   \
              /       \
            /           \
      UiObserver1   UiObserver2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little late answer but a slightly better option for your scenarion than the BehaviorSubject could be BehaviorRelay from [RxRelay lib](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxRelay). and also for more global solutions when you need different behaviors but want to share single point of interaction between all modules you can use [RxHub](https://github.com/apptik/rxHub)

Answer (score 8):

`BehaviorSubject` will fit your needs.
https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Subject#behaviorsubject

If you need more sophisticated behavior you can always write your own `Subject` implementation. It seems pretty straightforward to do so.

Comment: I ended up using `BehaviorSubject`, but I use an internal observer to only call onNext() when the parent Observable does, ignoring any onComplete events to keep the stream open. More info: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rxjava/2bNl14lIjRo

Comment: Ignoring onComplete is necessary in your case. I should have mentioned this in my answer, but this is clearly explained in the link I've posted.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is more simple if you use BehaviorSubject with switchOnNext operator.

[switchOnNext( )](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Combining-Observables#switchonnext)
convert an Observable that emits Observables (BehaviorSubject in this example) into a single Observable that emits the items emitted by the most-recently emitted of those Observables

the Observable returned by switchOnNext( ) unsubscribes from the previously-emitted Observable begins emitting items from the latest Observable

```
public class PhotoModel{
  BehaviorSubject<Observable<Photo>> subject = BehaviorSubject.create(...);

  public void setUserId(String id){
   subject.onNext(Api.getUserPhoto(photoId));
  }

  public Observable<Photo> subscribeToPhoto(){
    return Observable.switchOnNext(subject);
  }
}
```

[When should one use RxJava Observable and when simple Callback on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21890338/when-should-one-use-rxjava-observable-and-when-simple-callback-on-android/24185793#24185793)