# How to wait for callback with Retrofit, RxJava

Tags: java, android, rx-android

I am making multiple Retrofit requests and with every request I need to generate new client with new token. The problem is it is not waiting for it to finish so the client is `null`. I tried to add callback to `generatePrivateToken()` as well but it did not work.

```
public void generatePrivateToken(){
        mNewControl.obstest(GETTOKEN)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<Response<ResponseBody>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Response<ResponseBody> responseBodyResponse) {
                        key = responseBodyResponse.headers().get("Token");
                        new ApiKeys().encryptToken(key, new GeneralCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(String token) {
                                Log.e("Token", token);
                                client = new HttpClient(USERNAME,token, emptyTag, emptyTag).getClient();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete() {

                    }
                });
    }

public void getControlData(){
    generatePrivateToken();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(HOST_URL)
            .client(client)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    newControl service = retrofit.create(newControl.class);
    Call<List<GetControlData>> call = service.controlData(CONTROL);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<GetControlData>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<GetControlData>> call, Response<List<GetControlData>> response) {
            //do something, start new retrofit method
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<GetControlData>> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is well known and is why we need rx Observable over normal callback in Retrofit. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29918329/5282585).

Let's say you not want to make multiple retrofit requests and wait for all request have been finished, you can use the [zip operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)

Let’s first define our Retrofit object

```
Retrofit repo = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://api.github.com")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();

Observable<JsonObject> userObservable = repo
        .create(GitHubUser.class)
        .getUser(loginName)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());

Observable<JsonArray> eventsObservable = repo
        .create(GitHubEvents.class)
        .listEvents(loginName)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
```

simple POJO to combine the two objects:

```
public class UserAndEvents {
  public UserAndEvents(JsonObject user, JsonArray events) {
    this.events = events;
    this.user = user;
  }

  public JsonArray events;
  public JsonObject user;
}
```

then use RxJava’s zip method to combine our two Observables and wait for them to complete before creating a new Observable.

```
Observable<UserAndEvents> combined = Observable.zip(userObservable, eventsObservable, new Func2<JsonObject, JsonArray, UserAndEvents>() {
  @Override
  public UserAndEvents call(JsonObject jsonObject, JsonArray jsonElements) {
    return new UserAndEvents(jsonObject, jsonElements);
  }
});
```

For more details, visit the answer a give above, it's nice and fully explain.